# Oracle open office

Tags: openoffice

What's the difference between the free [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) and the non-free [Oracle Open Office](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/open-office/index.html)? The name collision is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Oracle Open Office FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/applications/open-office/043540.html):

> 6) What are the differences between Oracle Open Office and OpenOffice.org?
>
> At the core binary level there are no
>   differences. Oracle Open Office is
>   Oracle's professional distribution of
>   OpenOffice.org and customers
>   purchasing Oracle Open Office get:
>
> - Oracle warranty and indemnification
> - Ability to deploy hot fixes, patches and updates (OpenOffice.org
>     cannot be updated but requires a full
>     re-installation)
> - Enterprise extensions like MS SharePoint and Alfresco connectors
>     only available with Oracle Open Office
> - Enterprise Tools for help in migrating to Oracle Open Office—a
>     Microsoft Office document analyzer and
>     a tool that builds customized user
>     installations
> - Bundled extensions which are ready to use comes with Oracle Open
>     Office; with OpenOffice.org you have
>     to download each extension separately
> - Committed timelines and roadmaps
> - Customization opportunities

Comment: see also Wikipedia's [OO.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) and [Oracle Open Office/StarOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Open_Office) articles for the history of the products.

Comment: Sun Microsystems who were bought out by Oracle, use this as their general business model for software products.  Most of there stuff is available as a free/open source version, but then you can also get the version with support and all that jazz.  The support version I think is also a updated first.  The go as far as to do this with their OS, Solaris.

Comment: Take a look at LibreOffice. When around 2000 the OpenOffice peopĺe closed it off, they forked off and as far as I know have been racing ahead ever since.